# Handling UITabBarController and UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller, uilabel

I have created a UITabBarController and there are two views attached to it from tabBar.Whenever i run the application,i can see only two empty views. Whenever i add some items(image, label, text) to the other connected views,they aint getting displayed.

Comment: Do you use storyboard or code to do this?

Comment: I used StoryBoard :)